# Cannot debug nest js application in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, nestjs, vscode-debugger

I try to debug my nestjs application, I follow this article, https://javascript.plainenglish.io/debugging-nestjs-in-vscode-d474a088c63b but still cannot debug the application

This is my launch.json

```
   {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug Nest Framework",
            "args": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/api/src/main.ts"
            ],
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "--nolazy",
                "-r",
                "ts-node/register",
                "-r",
                "tsconfig-paths/register"
            ],
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/api",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "protocol": "inspector"
        }
```

when I debugging the app seems start debugging but after get this error

```
return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes)
           ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/companies/companies.service.ts:13:49 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Company'.
```

[image]

How can I debug this app?

Comment: How do you import the `Company` class?

Comment: Company is interface
interface Company {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  boardMembers?: { firstName: string; lastName: string }[];
}

Comment: AFIK you can launch the app with `./node_modules/.bin/nest start --exec "node --inspect-brk"` and select *Debug: attach to node process* in your command pallet

Comment: @24sharon okay., but how is it imported? Also to add on to @micael's comment you could just use `nest start --debug` (start:debug in the package.json) and attach to that process

Comment: WOW nest start --debug just work for me....  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No need to config luanch.json..

1. Open Vscode, and enter CTRL+SHIFT+P, select Toggle auto attach, choose always.
2. Click the code line you want to debug
3. npm run start

it will hit the line you want to debug

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting up an entire debug script, you can make use of the one Nest sets up in new applications for you. `start:debug` maps to `nest start --debug` which starts your server (after building it if needed) and adds the `--insert-brk` flag for node to know you need the debug port available. Then you can use `VSCode` to `attach` to port `9229` and start debugging.

Comment: Breakpoints do not hit.